# bitcoin payment accidentally sent to Bitcoin-Qt application's sending address

Tags: bitcoin-core, client

My father accidentally sent a bitcoin payment to his Bitcoin-Qt application's "sending address". Are the bitcoins lost? or is it possible to recover them somehow? When checking on blockchain.info, the funds are visible but I have no idea how to recover them into the Bitcoin-Qt wallet.

I thought it would be visible after his Bitcoin-Qt wallet synchronized but no luck. When referring to "sending address", when you go to sending address in the Bitcoin-Qt client it has one address (you can have multiple) but this was the address he sent the funds to. Unfortunately the bitcoins did not come back to his wallet. This was done 2 days ago. If I look up the same address on blockchain, the exact amount is just sitting there.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between sending and receiving addresses. If the address is his, the payment will become visible once his Bitcoin-Qt has synchronized with the network. (Unless with "sending address" you mean an address held by someone else that sent money to him.)